# Primary and secondary nameserver definition

Tags: dns, subdomain, nameservers

In my domain registar, I have accidentally defined my primary nameserver as ns2.mydomain.com, and secondary as ns1.mydomain.com

As I am having problems I wonder does it matter whats in the primary and whats in the secondary field?

Answer (score 1):

It shouldn't matter, which is the first and which is the second, if those servers are of equal capabilities, and both are responsible for your DNS zone(s). Your problems are less likely to originate from this issue, there is something else you are overlooking.

Comment: I have pretty strange situation. I have created and configured my reseller hosting account, incl
: defined private nameservers from welcome email 
: created A records for IPs 
: changed the nameservers on my domain registar 

I also added few accounts with on whm, and changed domain registar nameservers.

Comment: When I check whois, I see that nameservers are properly set, but I cannot see any folders for my accounts / domains on my server. 

Another thing is that my friend from another locations sees that the domain is placed on new server and working and I cannot see that. 

Also pretty weird thing is that I cannot render one domain to be active in Chrome and IE, but when I open Firefox I see that is placed and working on new servers. 


Im pretty confused.

Comment: `ipconfig /flushdns` ? Then check again.

Comment: Tried that. Still same. So this is the domain: www.infomint.hr 

I can see on whois that the nameservers are set to my domain: http://whois.com.hr/domena/infomint.hr/

The account is added in the WHM. There is no Ftp info on that domain listed. 

When I open it in firefox, I can see cgi bin, meaning it is working. 

When I open it in all other browser I get nothing. 

But everything seems fine here http://www.intodns.com/infomint.hr

Comment: It seems that there's a problem with your IE or maybe proxy settings. I see your site from both IE and Firefox.